# How can you optimize communications in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

For example: We have a Product object, this object displays about 40 fields, and 10 of these fields are links with other tables, for example City, User, and so on. Standard one-to-one and one-to-many relationships are used throughout.

So, if I display one object, then the speed is good, but if I display 1000 objects, then because of the large number of connections, the download speed is about 20 seconds. How can I optimize communications?

Comment: Can you show the queries you do? There is a package called Laravel Debug Bar which shows you the # of queries you execute. You might be able to cut down on queries if you use the `->with()` method to load all related tables in one query. Also pagination will improve performance. You might also be faster if you select only needed columns.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably want to use pagination, you can read about it in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination) .